# How to change Firestore rules in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase for the first time. In my project, someone has told me that I need to change my Firestore rules. Specifically he said "can you see this script it is firestore rules in firestore tab" and then posted:

[image]

I am reading the documentation, but it's going over my head. I just want to start by understanding where I find the Firestore rules first of all. I am in my Firebase project and in the "Firestore Database" section, but there is only a "Create atabase" button.

Or is this something that can only be done on the CLI?

Comment: If you're only starting with the firebase suite, I strongly encourage you to use the emulator first, and even if you don't, you should always edit your rules in a file referenced in your `firebase.json` file (something like `firestore.rules: './firestore.rules'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your database first and then you can find your Firestore rules right here.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I don't see those tabs, just a "Create database" button (I have edited my question). Do I need to create a database first to see those tabs?

Comment: Yes, first of all create your database and then you will see this section :)